# Reverse engineering a metric from its properties

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, systolic-geometry

I have been reading an article, and I am not clear on what he does in this one part.

He starts with a Riemmannian manifold $\Sigma$ that is $\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma$, a quotient of the hyperbolic space by some group of isometries. He then takes an isometry $\tau:\Sigma\rightarrow\Sigma$ and defines $M=\Sigma\times[0,1]/[(x,0)\sim(\tau(x),1)]$ the mapping torus.

It is claimed in the article that if you take a geodesic $\gamma$ in $M$ then the tube around it has a flat metric on it's boundary. This (unless in am missing something) is not true for the product metric. you can take $(t,\rho,z)$ to be your coordinates when $(t,\rho)$ are the Fermi coordinates in $\mathbb{H}^2$ then $ds^2=d\rho^2+cosh^2(\rho)dt^2+dz^2$ will not be flat at the boundary.

The boundary of a tube around a geodesic is flat, if you you think of a quotient of $\mathbb{H}^3$ (and that is what I originally thought he did) but $(x,r)\rightarrow(\tau(x),r+1)$ is not an isometry of $\mathbb{H}^3$, so you cant get $M=\mathbb{H}^3/G$.

Any thought on how this can be done?
I thank you all in advance

Comment: What article would that be?

Comment: I agree with @Will: a reference would go a long way.

Comment: The article is "Z2-sytolic freedom and Quantum codes" by M. Friedman.

Comment: The map has a finite order, so from Thurston the structure would be H^2xR. 

Comment: Are you sure Friedman doesn't just mean flat in the induced metric on the torus?  That's much weaker, and is trivially true in this case.

Comment: (I looked briefly at the article, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002124 , but didn't delve into it enough to see precisely what he needs.)

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what he meant, but I just took the simple product metric, and show that it has the properties that I want. Thank you all for your help.